# Pass a function value inside another function (Angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass a value from a function, to another one. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
      <li ng-repeat="language in languages" ng-click="myFirstFunction(firstValue)
             {{language.lang}}
      </li>
</div>
<div>
      <li ng-repeat="age in agess" ng-click="mySecondFunction(secondValue)
             {{age.year}}
      </li>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.myFirstFunction = function (firstValue) {
    console.log(firstValue);
}

$scope.mySecondFunction = function (secondValue) {
    console.log(secondValue);
}

$scope.myThirdFunction = function () {
    $scope.myFirstFunction(firstValue) // I need to import this value into this myThirdFunction()
    $scope.mySecondFunction(secondValue) // I need to import this value into this myThirdFunction()
    // console.log(firstValue);
    // console.log(secondValue)
}
```

I have 2 different functions because the value will arrive from 2 different clicks. I need to take this 2 values inside myThirdFunction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick modification to your JS code should do the trick.

```
let values = [];//place to store values
$scope.myFirstFunction = function (firstValue) {
    values[0] = firstValue;//stores first value
    console.log(firstValue);
}

$scope.mySecondFunction = function (secondValue) {
    values[1] = secondValue;//stores second value
    console.log(secondValue);
}

$scope.myThirdFunction = function () {
    // you can use the values here
    // console.log(values[0]);
    // console.log(values[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why not just save it to `$scope`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Staroselsky I wanted IronLjnc to not think of $scope to think that he has to use it, but if it was his intention to use it as a variable to carry the scope then I do not think he would have asked the question.

Comment: Thank you @JaimeArgila it's looking a good solution for me. Tomorrow i will try it!